# Passing authentication token in header swagger 3.0 (yaml)?

Tags: yaml, swagger

I have two API calls Login and Logout. 
First call (Login) is to generate Token based on user name and password. 
Second call needs token generated by first call.
How I set that token for second call using Swagger 3.0 ?

I have this yaml short code line as a starting point, if you have any welcome ideas

```
 /auth/credential/login:
        post:
          tags:
            - Credintial login
          summary: Logs in and returns the authentication cookie
          description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
          operationId: createUser
          security: []
          responses:
            '200':
              description: >-
                Successfully authenticated.
              headers:
                X-RateLimit-Limit:
                  schema:
                    type: integer
                    description: Request limit per hour.
                Set-Cookie:
                  schema:
                    type: string
                    description: Get token value
              content:
                application/json:
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Login'
                x-forwarded-for:
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Login'
            '202':
              description: Life is hard
              content:
                application/json:
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/LoginRespons'
                x-forwarded-for:
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/LoginRespons'
            '405':
              description: Invalid Login
          requestBody:
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Login'
            description: Created auth object
            required: true
      /auth/logout:
        post:
          tags:
            - Logout
          summary: Logout a user
          description: ''
          responses:
            '200':
              description: Success
              content:
                '*/*':
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Logout'
            '202':
              description: Success Logout!
              content:
                '*/*':
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/LogoutResponse'
            '405':
              description: Invalid Logout
          requestBody:
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Logout'
            description: description
```

Comment: Token = cookie? API key? Bearer token? How is this token supposed to be passed to the second call?